# How to implement custom authentication on function based view in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

if i have created a custom Authentication

```
class CustomAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        return super().authenticate(request)
```

how do I implement this in function based views?

Normally we can use decorators as

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication



@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
def view(request):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])` to your function

```py
@authentication_classes([CustomAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def view(request):
    pass
```